# what is deferent between <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> and <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Tags: java, hibernate

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                true
                create
                jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/redberry
                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            
        
    
and

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                true
                update
                jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/redberry
                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1):

With this `create` it will create a new schema every time you restart your server so your old tables data will be deleted:

```
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

And with this `update` you can update old tables:

```
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```